# SQL wild card from multiple fields but filtering only one column

Tags: sql

I am stuck on this query. It is fine when searching multiple columns but when I try to filter to just one department I get either everyone or no one depending on me using "AND / OR"

Here is my query

```
SELECT [Username] ,[Departmentname], [Field1], [Field2] 
FROM [test_table] 
WHERE [Departmentname] in ('Visitors')
  AND [Username] LIKE '%W%' 
  Or [Field1] LIKE '%W% 
  Or [Field2] LIKE '%W%'
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to correctly use parentheses around your conditions, such as

```
SELECT Username, Departmentname, Field1, Field2
FROM test_table 
WHERE Departmentname in ('Visitors')
AND ( 
  Username LIKE '%W%' 
  Or Field1 LIKE '%W% 
  Or Field2 LIKE '%W%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

"AND" has higher precedence than "OR".

You need to use parentheses.